# codeigniter ignoring custom validation function

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a login function in CodeIgniter with this code:

```
public function login() {
    $this->redirect_if_logged($this->login_check());
    $this->data['active'] = 'login';

    $this->load->model('user_model');       
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');     
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback__validate_login');

    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        $this->load->template('login', $this->data);
    } else {
        redirect('/','refresh');
    }       

}
```

And a validation function:

```
public function _validate_login($password) {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('_validate_login', 'Invalid username or password');
    return false;

}
```

The problem is that the custom function is never called, the validator always return true if all rules pass. The validator itself works, I checked it with other rules. It is just ignoring my custom function. What am I missing here?

Comment: did you debug inside `_validate_login` callback function, please try **`echo $password; die;`**

Comment: where is your _validate_login function?

Comment: I tried writing different things in that function, it always runs the redirect() line like it is not even checking that function. As in this example - I have set it to always return false, so it should not pass.

Comment: Both these functions are in the same controller.

Comment: i think `$this->redirect_if_logged($this->login_check());` is redirect page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation in your library

```
 class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{

    public function _validate_login($password) {
  $this->form_validation->set_message('_validate_login', 'Invalid username or password');
  return false;

}
```

in your controller remove callback

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password',  'trim|required|xss_clean|_validate_login')
```

Comment: This works, although I needed to add this `$CI =& get_instance();` and replace `this` with `CI` in the validator class. Thanks