# Callback to model

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, callback

I'm searching callback to model solution in `CodeIgniter`.
I have found a few solutions, but all of them are deprecated.
For [<kbd>example</kbd>](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/123780/)

Is possible any other solution to reach the intended effect ?
I really have no idea ;x

Comment: maybe this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405289/codeigniter-ignoring-custom-validation-function/22405680#22405680

Comment: Thanks, interesting solution but I have to implement to in model, without any additional libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do something using call_user_func ? php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

I'm not sure if you can callback to a model method, but per the documentation on PHP you can use nameSapce and call methods from a class:

```
<?php

class myclass {
    static function say_hello()
    {
        echo "Hello!\n";
    }
}

$classname = "myclass";

call_user_func(array($classname, 'say_hello'));
call_user_func($classname .'::say_hello'); // As of 5.2.3

$myobject = new myclass();

call_user_func(array($myobject, 'say_hello'));

?>
```